# in vs on vs at usage with respect to show advertisement at other location

Tags: word-choice, grammar, prepositions

```
show my ad in example.com
show my ad on example.com
show my ad at example.com
```

Which is correct here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you'd say "on".

It's to do with metaphors - what is a website?  I mean, how do we represent it mentally?

Is it a place?  If so, use "at".  Is it a page, like the page of a magazine?  If so, use "on".  Is it the whole magazine?  If so, use "in".

Most people have the "page" metaphor, even when talking about the whole site, which consists of many pages, and so would use "on".